# qTip with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, qtip2

Am trying to get qtip2 working with a rails3 application.

qtip's working great but I can't figure out how to get it to work with dynamic content from my models. Am stuck formatting my js...

In my view, I'm trying the following:

```
<li><%= link_to milestone.name, order_path(milestone.order_id), { 'data-href' => :name, :class => 'selector' }  %> </li>
```

(I've only put :name in there to test)

This renders as html:

```
<li><a href="/orders/1" class="selector" data-href="name">Setup Equipment</a> </li>
```

Which looks ok.

In my application.js, I have this:

```
$('.selector').qtip({
        content: $(this).attr('data-href')
 });
```

I think I have something wrong with my content syntax. I can see the tooltip if I replace with:

```
$('.selector').qtip({
        content: 'test'
 });
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: you want qtip to work with dynamically added elements to the `DOM` ?

Comment: do you have multiple elements in the page that have the class `selector`

Comment: He should wrap that call inside a function

Comment: Hello. Yeah, I actually have a calendar of events built using table_builder. There's a load of them on the page with the selector class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should do :

```
$('.selector').qtip({

    content: function(){
        return $(this).data('href');
    }

});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/cnkJU/2/

Comment: hmmm. Thanks for this. Can see it working on jsfiddle but can't get the bugger to work at our end!

Comment: have you got firebug?what error message do you have in the console?

Comment: Got it working!! Had placed it in a stupid part of my js... Oops. The only thing I changed though was .attr('data-href')

Comment: data('href') works from jquery 1.4.4 onwards, maybe you have an old version of jquery

Comment: We must have sent that at the same time. Yeah, it's working now. Thanks again :)

Comment: I am not seeing the fiddle working with any type of qtip tooltip ,  stumbled across this stackoverflow question/answer and perhaps i don't know all that qtip "does"     I have javascript generate dynamic content and the qtip in did in a fiddle worked but not in my real project